# Finding array entry closest to required value, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, each with a property 'time'. The array is already sorted by time. I now want to find the entry idx, such that:

```
  findIdx(time): return idx where idx <= time < idx+1
```

While I can loop through the entries and return as soon as I have found a corresponding entry, I am concerned this will be very heavy in the use case I have. The use case is scrubbing though a video, so the list would likely be looped through frequently during that action.

My current thought is to create a tree of increasingly precise times, such that I would reduce the looping through the list, by only querying the appropriate ranges.

I may be overthinking the problem, but any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If the array is sorted, you can use a binary search to lower the CPU cost.

Comment: Exactly, and if the array is not sorted, sort it and then use binary search. It would take you O(nlogn), which is pretty good :).

Comment: Note that for creating a balanced binary tree it would take O(nlogn), thus doing that and searching would also take O(nlogn). Which means you'd spend as much time as sorting and doing a binary search. However, I believe that sorting and doing a binary search would be quicker to implement.

Comment: @Draco18s Do you want to convert your comment into an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, if the array is sorted, you can use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to lower the CPU cost.

A second advantage to a binary search algorithm is that if the value is not contained in the array, you also know what index it *would* be at, making insertion (and maintaining the sorted nature of the array) easy.